# Using lambda function as key in sort

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

Can someone please explain how this code works. How the isisnstance function in the lambda function sorts the list

```
def db_sort(arr):
    return sorted(arr, key=lambda x: (isinstance(x,str) ,x))
db_sort(['a', 'w', 'u', 'y', 6, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

output:

> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'a', 'u', 'w', 'y']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lambda function creates tuples of a Boolean value and the original value itself. So `sorted` is applied on the following input:

```
(True, 'a') (True, 'w') (True, 'u') (True, 'y') (False, 6) (False, 2) (False, 3) (False, 4) (False, 5)
```

It puts the entries with a `False` entry first, and then the `True` elements (the strings in this example). Then it sorts the `False` elements in logical order after the second tuple entry and the `True` elements in logical order as well. Think of it as a kind of hierarchical sorting.

So you end up with

```
(False, 6) (False, 2) (False, 3) (False, 4) (False, 5) (True, 'a') (True, 'w') (True, 'u') (True, 'y')
```

after the first level of sorting and with

```
(False, 2) (False, 3) (False, 4) (False, 5) (False, 6) (True, 'a') (True, 'u') (True, 'w') (True, 'y')
```

after the second level. This way you end up with the final order of your array (I suppose you missed `6` accidentally).

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'a', 'u', 'w', 'y']
```